# complex numbers $z^n = 1$ complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, roots-of-unity

I would like to know if I answered the question below correctly or if I need to change something.

> Question: Take $n ∈ \mathbb N$. Find all solutions for $z^n=1$. Where can we find the solutions in the complex plane? Draw them in the complex plane for some values of $n$.**

$z^n = 1$ and $ n ∈ \mathbb N$. Assumption: $ 1 = e^{i0} = e^{i2π} = e^{i4π} = e^{i2(2π)} $.

$z^n = 1$ and $ n ∈ \mathbb N$.

= $ \cos (0) + i \sin (0)  $, (as $r = 1$)

= $ \cos (0+2kπ) + i \sin (0+2kπ)$

= $ \cos (2kπ) + i \sin (2kπ) $,    this gives us $ e^{i(2kπ)} $ with $k ∈ \mathbb Z$.

$z^n = 1$, so $z=\sqrt[n]{1 }$  and $z = 1^{1/n}$.

Using deMoivre's theorem, we get $ z = [e^{i(2kπ)}]^{1/n} $ =

$ z = e^{i2π(k/n)} ,  k = 0,1,2,...,n-1 $ with $ n ∈ \mathbb N$ .

Using deMoivre's theorem again, we get $ z = [\cos(2kπ) + i \sin (2kπ)]^{1/n} = \cos (2kπ/n) + i \sin (2kπ/n) $.

---

Now, we draw the solutions for some values of $n$ in the complex plane.

$ n = 1  \to z = 1 $ gives $ \cos (2kπ) + i \sin (2kπ) $, so $ z = 1 $.

$ n = 2  \to z = 1^{1/2} $ gives $ \cos (2kπ/2) + i \sin (2kπ/2) = \cos (kπ/2) + i \sin (kπ/2) $ , so $ z = 1, -1 $.

$ n = 3   \to z = 1^{1/3} $ gives $ \cos (2kπ/3) + i \sin (2kπ/3) $ , so $ z = -1/2 + 1/2√3 i, -1/2 - 1/2√3 i, 1 $ .

$ n = 4  \to z = 1^{1/4} $ gives $ \cos (2kπ/4) + i \sin (2kπ/4) = \cos (kπ/2) + i \sin (kπ/2) $, so $z = i, -1, -i, 1$.

Did I do it right? Should I change something in my notation?

Comment: You should change "plain" to "plane" throughout, and you should learn how to format math on this website. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and/or https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto

Comment: For formatting math please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Without proper formatting your post is very difficult to read.

Comment: I'd suggest beginning by taking it as a given that all nonzero degree $n$ complex coefficient polynomials in a single complex variable $z$ have exactly $n$ roots counted with multiplicity. This is the fundamental theorem of algebra, the proof of which is likely beyond the scope of your current studies. Then, knowing that there are exactly $n$ roots to $z^n=1$, demonstrate that the roots of unity are indeed its roots.

Comment: General considerations about polynomials are useless here and the solutions are (by definition) the $n$-th roots of unity. That said, your results are correct (though you don't answer the question "where [...]") but your "proof" is bad. It is a good idea to use de Moivre's theorem, but correctly. Don't raise any complex number to the power $1/n$ (this means nothing to you). Instead, plug $z=re^{i\theta}$ into your equation $z^n=1$ and solve it for $(r,\theta)$.

Comment: You're on the right track. The polar form reveals their location and you've correctly identified the first few roots.

Comment: @AnneBauval Considerations of polynomials are requirements for specifying the solution set. Without assuming FTA, we could have had an $(n+1)$'th root and not be certain that we have described "all" solutions, as the question desired. But regardless, Euler's formula or de Moivre's theorem are what would verify the roots, as the OP had attempted.

Comment: @Jam I don't understand it, could you edit my post with the fundamental theorem in it? Or do I have to start over?

Comment: @Willem You don't have to *use* FTA, I'm saying you ought to know that it's true. If you have a degree $n$ complex polynomial, it's got $n$ roots. So you can be confident that you've successfully found "all" of the roots, given that you have $n$ of them, so there isn't another cryptic one that you've missed out.

Comment: @Jam (and Willem) I maintain that neither using FTA nor even being aware of it is helpful. If you solve methodically the equation as I sketched, and as Lorago did in his (very standard) answer, you can be absolutely certain to have found *all* the solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more straightforward way to solve this would be to use that two nonzero complex numbers are equal if and only if their modules are equal, and their arguments are equal modulo $2\pi$ in the following way.

Write

$$z=re^{i\theta},$$

and note that your equation then reads

$$r^ne^{in\theta}=1.$$

Since $r^n=\lvert z^n\rvert=1$ by matching modulo, we have that $r=1$, and so $z=e^{i\theta}\ne0$. Furthermore, by matching arguments,

$$\exists k\in\mathbb{Z},\quad n\theta=2\pi k,$$

i.e.

$$\exists k\in\mathbb{Z},\quad\theta=\frac{2\pi k}n.$$

This gives the possible solutions as

$$z=e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}}$$

for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. It is also easy to check (by plugging into the original equation) that these are indeed solutions for any choice of $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Finally, notice that

$$e^{i\frac{2\pi (k+n)}{n}}=e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}}e^{i2\pi}=e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}},$$

and so there are only $n$ solutions, which can be found by taking, for example, $k=0,1,\dots, n-1$.

Comment: (+1) but it might be advisable for posterity to clarify that "$k\in\mathbf{Z}$" means "for _some_ integer $k$." When a quantifier is omitted, it's generally understood to mean "for _every_...."

Comment: Done. I also wanted to add somewhere that the "*possible* solutions $z=e^{i\frac{2k\pi}n}$" *are* in fact solutions, either by a small sentence before "Finally, notice [...]", or by replacing all along $\Rightarrow$ by $\Leftrightarrow$. I prefer the second option but it is a matter of taste, and I didn't dare to modify that much your answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval I don’t understand what you mean with your last comment, but it’s okay you can edit the comment so I can see  and then I’ll mark it as the right answer 

Comment: @AnneBauval yeah good point, I should probably write that as well

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to solve would be:
$$
\begin{align*}
z^{n} &= 1 \Rightarrow z^{n} = |z^{n}|\\
z &= |z| \cdot \mathrm{e}^{\arg(z) \cdot \mathrm{i}}
(|z| \cdot \mathrm{e}^{\arg(z) \cdot \mathrm{i}})^{n} &= 1\\
|z|^{n} \cdot (\mathrm{e}^{\arg(z) \cdot \mathrm{i}})^{n} &= 1\\
|z|^{n} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{n \cdot \arg(z) \cdot \mathrm{i}} &= 1\\
\mathrm{e}^{n \cdot \arg(z) \cdot \mathrm{i}} &= 1 \quad\mid\quad (\text{ 
})^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
\mathrm{e}^{\arg(z) \cdot \mathrm{i}} &= 1^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
\mathrm{e}^{\arg(z) \cdot \mathrm{i}} &= \pm \sqrt{1}\\
\mathrm{e}^{\arg(z) \cdot \mathrm{i}} &= \pm 1\\
&\Rightarrow \mathrm{e}^{\arg(z) \cdot \mathrm{i}} = \Re(\mathrm{e}^{\arg(z) \cdot \mathrm{i}})\\
&=\Rightarrow \arg{z} = 2 \cdot \frac{k_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} + n}{n} \cdot \pi
\end{align*}
$$

That means that there are n solutions with $$ k = 1, ~2, ~..., ~n - 1, $$
wich means that there are mure solutios for z then $$ z = \left\{1, ~i, ~-1, ~-i\right\}, $$ aka you should change this.
e.g.
$$
\begin{align*}
z &= \frac{\mathrm{1}}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{2}}\\
z^{4} &= (\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{2}})^{4}\\
z^{4} &= (1^{\frac{1}{4}})^{4}\\
z^{4} &= 1
\end{align*}
$$